# Prevent date converting in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm try to read data from en excel file to insert them in a table.
I have a column with general formating, it can contains any thing. Testing the validaty is done by code. My problem is when i read an integer/double, 23 for exemple, it's converted to 1900-01-22 which is not logic in my case.
The follwing is my code to connect and read from excel

```
Dim rsExcel As Object
Set cnnExcel = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsExcel = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
With cnnExcel
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=D:\Query1.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"
    .CursorLocation = 3
    .Open
End With    
rsExcel.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet 1$]", cnnExcel
' to read the column
rsExcel.Fields(3).Value
```

Is there any way to prevent this automatic conversion

Thank you for your help

Comment: Try adding "Data Source=D:\Query1.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;IMEX=1"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I added actually that property but did not help

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Value2` property instead of `Value`. `Value2` ignores currency and date data types i.e without any formatting.

Comment: I don't think there's a method called Value2!

Comment: @Bes-mM-bes Yes, you're right, my mistake. `Value2` only exists within Excel whereas you are using a recordset from a worksheet. Out of interest, why are you doing this? Doesn't really make sense to me why you would want to parse a worksheet into a recordset when you could just read the worksheet.

Comment: Yeah you're right! What I need is to read the excel file no more no less but the problem if I use : objWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Value this is so tight to the order of the columns, where rsExcel.Fields("columnName").Value go directly to the "columnName" the index of the column is not a problem.

Comment: @Bes-mM-bes I see. Not the way I would go but still. In that case, I don't think there is a way to specify the datatype as I believe ADO will 'guess' based on the first couple of rows. if the datatype is important, then I would suggest avoiding this method.

Comment: Actually the datatype is not important. I want only to read the excel file. In the cells the user can write anything. If in the column "RegDate" the user write 123 so i have to say that 123 is not a valid date the same if he write abc. But the problem is when i use rsExcel.Fields("RegDate").Value, vba take it as double and convert it to old date and IsDate function return true in that case.